# ASPxGridView single selection

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress

Im trying to figure out how can I make singelSelection on ASPxGridView.

The onClick event handled like that:

```
function GvUsersSelectionChanged(selectedRow) {
        //Clear the text selection
        if (GvUserClient.IsRowSelectedOnPage(selectedRow.visibleIndex)) {
            GvUserClient.SelectRow(selectedRow.visibleIndex, false);
            return;
        }
        GvUserClient.UnselectRows();
        GvUserClient.SelectRow(selectedRow.visibleIndex, true);
    }
```

all rows are unselected :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to turn off multiselect mode and set the ASPxGridView's SettinsBehavior.AllowFocusedRow property to true.  Also, we have published the following examples:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E13.aspx
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E135.aspx